# Each element of list into a separate pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of list with soil physical properties, each element of the list represents a different location. is there a way to save each element of the list as a separate pandas data frame. When I try to transform the complete list I get the error message:
`ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 19, 18)`

Comment: Put a sample of "a list of list".

Comment: this is one of the elements of the list:
```
  cokey     chkey prcent slope_r slope hzname deptht depthb   awc clay  \
3  21830488  64387489     85       1     1     H1      0     25  0.12   11   
4  21830488  64387490     85       1     1     H2     25     76  0.12   14   
6  21830488  64387491     85       1     1     H3     76    152  0.12   14

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of lists is included in another list, if you slice it with [0,:,:] you'll resolve that error.  However, there's not enough information in your question to completely ensure your load to separate dataframes will work.  Here's an example of how to reshape to 2-d input:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]])

In [2]: a.shape
Out[2]: (1, 2, 3)

In [3]: a[0,:,:].shape  #2D array
Out[3]: (2, 3)
```